# Is it possible to add padding and margin to each widgets in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to apply margin and padding to each widgets is that possible in kivy?

Here is the exact image I need; I want to apply padding and margin to each button:

![1][1]

I applied one method in kivy, put the widget in 2 layouts but the problem is without adding margin, padding there is space between the widgets. How can we set the 2 layout size according to widget size? Here is my code:

[image: code main.py]

kv file

[image: got like this]

```
<Demoproject>:
    Screen:
        name:"screen_2917"
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)
            Rectangle:

                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
                #source:""

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"vertical"



            BoxLayout:
                orientation:"vertical"
                padding:dp(0),dp(0),dp(0),dp(0)
                color:(1,0,0,1)
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgb: [.10, .10, .10]
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                GridLayout:
                    cols:1
                    padding:dp(0),dp(0),dp(0),dp(0)
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb: [.6, .6, .6]
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    Button:
                        text:"close"
                        size:(200,100)
                        size_hint:(None,None)



            BoxLayout:
                orientation:"vertical"
                padding:dp(0),dp(0),dp(0),dp(0)
                color:(1,0,0,1)

                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgb: [.10, .10, .10]
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                GridLayout:
                    cols:1
                    padding:dp(0),dp(0),dp(0),dp(0)
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb: [.6, .6, .6]
                        Rectangle:
                            pos:self.pos
                            size:self.size
                    Button:
                        text:"close"
                        size:(200,100)
                        size_hint:(None,None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your `kv` file and just use `padding` and `spacing`. Like this:

```
<Demoproject>:
    Screen:
        name:"screen_2917"
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
                #source:""

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"vertical"
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.minimum_size
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
            padding: 5  # between Boxlayout edges and Buttons
            spacing: 5  # between Buttons
            Button:
                text:"close"
                size:(200,100)
                size_hint:(None,None)
            Button:
                text:"close"
                size:(200,100)
                size_hint:(None,None)
```

Padding can only be applied by a few of the `Layout` classes. So if you want different `padding` for each `Button`, you must use separate `Layouts`. Here is another version of your `kv` that uses `AnchorLayout` to apply different `padding` for each `Button`:

```
<Demoproject>:
    Screen:
        name:"screen_2917"
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
                #source:""

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"vertical"
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.minimum_size
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:(0,1,0,1)
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size:self.size
            AnchorLayout:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: butt1.width + self.padding[0] + self.padding[2], butt1.height + self.padding[1] + self.padding[3]
                padding: 20
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1,0,0,1
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                Button:
                    id: butt1
                    text:"close"
                    size:(200,100)
                    size_hint:(None,None)
            AnchorLayout:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: butt2.width + self.padding[0] + self.padding[2], butt2.height + self.padding[1] + self.padding[3]
                padding: 5, 10, 15, 20
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0,0,1,1
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                Button:
                    id: butt2
                    text:"close"
                    size:(200,100)
                    size_hint:(None,None)
```

The `canvas` instructions are just to more easily visualize what is happening. The `AnchorLayout` sizes are calculated to just fit the `Button` with the  specified `padding`.

Comment: See updated answer.